# Is there a way to write a single backslash in monospace (code) format in comments?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

In a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511709/mapbox-api-requests-for-static-map-and-polyline/65523379) I couldn't figure out how to write a single backslash in code formatting: `\`. Is there a way?

Comment: ```\``` You can quote the backslash in triple backticks.

Comment: I was gonna ask how you managed to do it in your question here then, but I guess this is one of those cases where we use different markdown parsing rules in comments for some reason.

Comment: [See this comment in the Formatting Sandbox](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/289905#comment1174312_3122): [SOBotics Tool](//tools.sobotics.org/tools/get-body-comment/) to get the source text of this comment. Single backslash and single backtick: ``\``, `\``. Type: `\`\`\\`\`, \`\\`\``.

Answer (score 10):

You can write this in a comment:

```
``\``
```

and it will appear as a code-formatted backslash. I thought it required three backticks each side, but apparently two is the minimum.

Comment: Ah, the old triple backslash. Why didn't I think of that. ```\``` Are you able to explain why it works?

Comment: Only that comments support a different subset of markdown from questions and answers, and with single backticks the backslash can be interpreted as escaping the backtick.

Comment: I mean though, why three backticks exactly?

Comment: @SteveBennett could have been worse if they kept in line with the 6 to 8 meme ...